# Express middleware is not in sequence order

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, firebase-admin

I am trying to use `firebase-admin` to authenticate my backend express server. The endpoint is triggered from a React app.

Below are my codes on my server.

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const inventoryRoutes = require('./routes/inventoryRoutes');

//global middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method);
    next();
})

//routes
app.use('/api',inventoryRoutes);

//welcome route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})



//Database connection
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.wbmcg.mongodb.net/skus?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, { dbName: "inventoryDB" })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected to db');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })


//start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Inventory server is running on port ", port);
})
```

in `inventoryRoutes.js` route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getUserToken, authenticatedUser } = require('../middleware/userAuthMiddleware')

//create a warehouse
router.post('/createwarehouse', getUserToken, authenticatedUser, postNewWarehouse)

module.exports = router
```

In the middleware `userAuthMiddleware.js`

```
const admin = require('../firebase-config')


const getUserToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decodedValue = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
    console.log("at getUserToken middleware, logged in user email is ->  ", decodedValue.email);
    req.email = decodedValue.email;
    next()
}


const authenticatedUser = ( req, res, next ) => {
    admin.auth().listUsers()
        .then(response => {
            connectedUser = req.email;
            console.log("at authenticatedUser middleware, logged in user email is ->  ",connectedUser);

            const user = [];
            response.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
                user.push(userRecord.toJSON().email)
            })
            // console.log(user);
            const email = user.find(newuser => newuser === connectedUser)
            console.log(email, "  -> email is found in user list");
            
        })
    next()
}

module.exports = {
    authenticatedUser,
    getUserToken
}
```

I am expecting that middlewares should work in the order they were written. `i.e. getUserToken> authenticatedUser> postNewWarehouse` in `inventoryRoutes.js` route. But i am getting the following output where `postNewWarehouse` middleware is triggered before `authenticatedUser` middleware.

Output....

```
/api/createwarehouse POST
at getUserToken middleware, logged in user email is ->   hello1@gello.com
from the main function of the route ->  { name: 'ertyyju', space: '23456', description: 'New warehouseerty' }
at authenticatedUser middleware, logged in user email is ->   hello1@gello.com
hello1@gello.com   -> email is found in user list
```

in `inventoryRoutes.js` route, i tried to combine the first two middlewares in an array, but no luck.

```
const middlewares = [getUserToken, authenticatedUser]
router.post('/createwarehouse', middlewares, postNewWarehouse)
```

Can anybody help me figure out, why the last middleware is executed before the previous one?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you put `next()` **inside** the `.then()` callback?

Comment: Thanks @Phil , it worked. I guess I need to clear my concept more :)